# Golang equivalent of JavaScript's arguments?

Tags: go, arguments

Is there a golang way to get a function's runtime arguments?

I'm asking because I'm trying to write a function that takes a function and a string, and then outputs the string and the runtime arguments.

Comment: Go is a statically typed and compiled language. You have to define the arguments for your function in order for it to compile.

Comment: Are you looking for [variadic functions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types)?

Comment: I'm not looking for variadic functions, no. JimB's answer covered me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript where a function can be called with extra arguments not included in the declaration, calls to Go functions must match the function signature.  So there isn't a need for the special `arguments` global.

With that said, it is possible to write variadic functions that can take a variable number of arguments.  For example, the following function will accept a string followed by any number of integer arguments:

```
func foo(s string, args ...int) {
    ...
}
```

In the function body `args` will be an `[]int` slice, so you can determine how many arguments were passed with `len`, and iterate through them as you would with any other slice.

If you want to accept arguments of any type, you can use the blank interface as the type:

```
func bar(args ...interface{}) {
    ...
}
```

Now `args` will be an `[]interface{}` slice.  You can unpack the values passed in using a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) or [type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches).